# sending jquery call to external url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

Here's my call to external api in angular js

```
$http.post('http://api.quickblox.com/users.json', {
    token: quickbloxapitoken,
    user: {
        email: email,
        login: firstname,
        password: password
    }
        }, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })
        .then(function(results) {
            var apiid = results.data.user.id;
     }
```

**Here my data is sent in two json array like this**

[image]

And when i try to do the same in jquery i have my call like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.quickblox.com/users.json',
    type : 'POST',  
     data: { token: quickbloxapitoken, login: fbname, password: 'fbuserfbuser', email: fbmail},
    success: function(message)
    {
    console.log(message);
    }
    })
```

The datas was sent  like this

[image]

How can i make my jquery datas sent like the angularjs one ?

I mean like this ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the request `contentType` as `application/json`.

Also, if you expect JSON in return, you'd better include the `dataType` as well (although it's probably automatically guessed):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.quickblox.com/users.json',
    type : 'POST',  
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
       token: quickbloxapitoken,
       user: {
         login: fbname,
         password: 'fbuserfbuser',
         email: fbmail
       }
    })
});
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks.. I changed the `contentType` but my data should be `token` in first json and `email,login,password` in second json. Like the final screenshot i given..

Comment: @user4989228 I modified the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks, but i am getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.quickblox.com/users.json'` error :( You have any idea about this  ?

Comment: @user4989228, See my update. I missed the `JSON.stringify` part.

Comment: @user4989228, Please do not expose real authentication credentials. Also, it's seems like you're not using my revised answer that is including the call to `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Thanks that token is generated every minute and i didn't expose my credentials ;) Thanks for the advice and answer. Cheers :)